# Start tag head seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html

I have tried to process my web page in the W3C validator. But it always shows that the Start tag head seen but an element of the same type was already open.But If I remove the start tag of `<head>`,it passed. If I add the start tag, the error arises again. Why does this happen.
Here is the my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
table,th,td{
    border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<head>
<title>Rui's Calendar</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
 <body>
  <h1>Rui's Calendar</h1>
  <table style="width 100%">
   <tr style="color: blue">
     <th>
      <p>Monday</p> 
     </th>
     <td>
      <p><i>9:00-9:50 AM</i><br>PHY 1302 Willey Hall</p>    
     </td>
     <td>
      <p><i>11:00-12:00 AM</i><br>  -   </p>
     </td>
     <td>
     <p><i>5:45-6:30 PM</i><br>CSCI 4041 Akerman Hall</p>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="color:red">
     <th>
      <p>Tuesday</p>    
     </th>
     <td>
      <p><i>9:00-9:50 AM</i><br>PHY 1302 <a href="http://campusmaps.umn.edu/willey-hall"></a>>Willey Hall</p>
     </td>
     <td>
      <p><i>1:00-2:15 PM</i><br>CSCI 4707 Fraser Hall</p>
     </td>
     <td>
     <p><i>2:30-3:45 PM</i><br>CSCI 4131 Bruininks Hall</p>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="color: blue">
     <th>
      <p>Wednesday</p>
     </th>
     <td>
      <p><i>9:00-9:50 AM</i><br>PHY 1302 Blegen Hall</p>    
     </td>
     <td>
      <p><i>1:00-2:15 PM</i><br>-</p>
     </td>
     <td>
     <p><i>2:30-3:45 PM</i><br>-</p>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="color: red">
     <th>
      <p>Thursday</p>   
     </th>
     <td>
      <p><i>9:00-9:50 AM</i><br>PHY 1302 Blegen Hall</p>    
     </td>
     <td>
      <p><i>1:00-2:15 PM</i><br>CSCI 4707 <a href="http://campusmaps.umn.edu/fraser-hall">Fraser Hall</a></p>
     </td>
     <td>
     <p><i>2:30-3:45 PM</i><br>CSCI 4131 Bruininks Hall</p>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="color: blue">
     <th>
      <p>Friday</p>>    
     </th>
     <td>
      <p><i>9:00-9:50 AM</i><br>PHY 1302 Willey Hall</p>    
     </td>
     <td>
      <p><i>1:00-2:15 PM</i><br>-</p>
     </td>
     <td>
     <p><i>2:30-3:45 PM</i><br>-</p>
     </td>
   </tr>


  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error "Start tag `head` seen but an element of the same type was already open." occurs because the start tag for the head element is optional.

Since the style element can only exist inside the head, the parser knows to open the head element when it encounters the `<style>`, basically inserting an invisible `<head>` start tag.
No error or warning is generated there, because, as I said, the `<head>` start tag is optional. Leaving it out is fine. (Not recommended though.)
But then the parser encounters your `<head>` start tag, and the error occurs, because the head was already open!

Hope this explains things.

Answer (score 0):

If you must include the style tag, include it inside the head tag. This should fix your error. Preferably, you would use a separate CSS file for the styling though.